# Построение пирамиды в консоли

Tags: c, консоль

Здравствуйте!

Помогите решить задачу (из книжки), написать нужно на СИ.
[image]

Я смог только составить 2 цикла, которая печатает буквы:

```
ch = ch1 = ch2;  //Буква, которую ввёл пользователь

for ( ch; ch >= 'A'; ch--) // в порядке убывания
{
    printf("%c", ch);
}

for ( i = 'A'; i <= ch1; i++) //в порядке возрастания
{
    printf("%c", i);
}
```

Решение данной задачи я так же нагуглил, но совершенно не понял.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, Вы предлагаете всем погуглить **условие задачки**?

Comment: @avp, я же условие задачи выложил. На скриншоте оно есть.
Меня интересует не объяснение чужого решения из гугла, а чьё то решение с разъяснением.

Comment: Я уже 2 день не могу решить эту задачу. Уже задолбался.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, Вы выложили (по крайней мере я, здесь, в вопросе, вижу только это) кусочек какого-то кода, 

а не то, что *требуется* получить и из каких исходных данных.

А про гугл я говорил - поиск **условия** (т.е. что требуется делать), а не решения.

Странно, что за 2.5 года пребывания на форуме Вы так и не нучились *проавильно* задавать вопросы.

Comment: @avp, мне кажется, что только Вы не видите условие задачи.

Comment: Вот теперь вижу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте разобьём задачу на части, будет всё просто.

У нас есть `k` строк. Чтобы напечатать их, надо, понятно, цикл по номеру строки от 0 до `k - 1`. Хорошо.

Что должно быть в `i`-ой строке?

Для начала, в строке есть несколько пробелов. Сколько? В последней строке (её номер `k-1`) 0 штук, в предпоследней (её номер `k-2`) один, и так далее. Значит, в `i`-ой строке у нас `k - 1 - i` пробелов в начале. Есть?

Затем, там идут буквы от `A` по возрастанию. Сколько их в `i`-ой строке? В 0-й одна, в 1-ой две и т. д. То есть, `i + 1` штук. Таким образом, нам нужен внутренний цикл от 0 до `i`, в котором мы выдаём новую букву. Видите?

Затем, начиная от последней буквы вниз до `A` выдаём их в обратном порядке. Подумайте, как это можно сделать.

В конце строки не забывайте `\n`.

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD :)

    import Control.Monad
    main = do
        putStrLn "Введите число строк"
        n <- getLine >>= return . read :: IO Int
        foldM_ (\(n, p) c -> putStrLn (replicate (n - 1) ' ' ++ reverse p ++ [c] ++ p) >> return (n-1, c:p)) (n, []) (take n ['A'..])

Прошу прощения, забыл константу 10 поменять на n. Fixed

Comment: @alexlz:

    Console.Write("Введите число строк");
    var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine);
    Func<IEnumerable<char>, string> composeString = seq => new string(seq.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Join("\n", Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                .Select(k => composeString(Enumerable.Range('A', k + 1).Select(i => (char)i)))
                .Select(l => new string(' ', n - l.Length) + l + composeString(l.Reverse().Skip(1)))));

Comment: @alexlz: Хотя конструкция `['A'..]` классная, у C# такого нет из коробки. Хотя, конечно, однострочник.

Comment: @alexlz: http://pastebin.com/FTFFbBsv. Добавить вокруг кода функцию `Main` и недостающие using-директивы. `namespace` по вкусу. Добавить скобки после `ReadLine` :-)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. Поскольку System.Collections.Generic и System.LINQ мне пришлось бы в доках искать. Работает.

Comment: @alexlz: Visual Studio умеет полуавтоматически добавлять недостающий using, я избалован этой фичей.

Comment: @alexlz: по сравнению с вашим кодом у меня (1) `Enumerable.Range('A', k + 1).Select(i => (char)i)` вместо `take n ['A'..]` (был бы `Range` более универсальным, такое извращение было бы не нужно); (2) я использую `string.Join` вместо `fold`, т. к. фолдить выражения с побочными эффектами (`putStrLn`) в C# считается неправильным.

Comment: @alexlz: Хе, в C# `Select` и `Range` как раз ленивые. Весь LINQ — это ленивые вычисления (за исключением fold'ов, которые энергичные). Так что проблем с бесконечными итераторами не должно быть.

Comment: @VladD увы, про LINQ я знаю только, что оно есть. А уж семантика его мне просто неведома.

Раз Вы такой пурист, то вынесем печать из fold'а и заменим `['A'..]` эквивалентом enumFrom 'A'

    main = do
        putStrLn "Введите число строк"
        n <- getLine >>= return . read :: IO Int
        putStr $ unlines $ reverse $ fst $ foldl (\(r, l) c -> 
            ((replicate (n - length l - 1) ' ' ++ reverse l ++ [c] ++ l):r, c:l))
            ([], []) $ take n $ enumFrom 'A'

Comment: @alexlz: У вас немного эффективнее: `['A', 'AB', 'ABC'...]` у вас считается через fold, а у меня через вложенную реэнумерцию (внутренний `Enumerable.Range('A', k + 1)`). Мне не нравятся функции с побочными эффектами в `fold` потому, что результат может быть использован ленивым образом или вообще никогда, что в зависимости от реализации `fold`'а может выполнить не все запланированные побочные эффекты. Против `['A'..]` ничего не имею (может, по незнанию).

Answer (score 3):

У меня такой код получился.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{ 
    char ch = getch();

    printf("%c\n", ch);

    if (ch < 'A' || ch > 'X') {
        printf("Error input char\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int lines = ch - 'A' + 1;

    int rcount;
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < lines - i; x++) {
            printf("%c", ' ');
        }

        for(int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
            printf("%c", 'A' + s);
            rcount = s;
        }

        for(int d = rcount, c = 1; d > 0; d--, c++) {
            printf("%c", 'A' + rcount - c);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

А как объяснение кода попробуйте использовать ответ [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) но с небольшими изменениями.

P.S. Ну если нельзя в С определять переменные в середине кода, а нужно тока в начале, то код получится таким.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{ 
    char ch = getch();
    int i, x, s, d, c, rcount;
    int lines;

    printf("%c\n", ch);

    if (ch < 'A' || ch > 'X') {
        printf("Error input char\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    lines = ch - 'A' + 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {

        for (x = 0; x < lines - i; x++) {
            printf("%c", ' ');
        }

        for(s = 0; s < i; s++) {
            printf("%c", 'A' + s);
        }

        rcount = s - 1;

        for(d = rcount, c = 1; d > 0; d--, c++) {
            printf("%c", 'A' + rcount - c);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, если не секрет, чем компилируете данный код?

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, вы забыли объявить переменную "с" используемую в третьем цикле.   
Ещё раз спасибо за код.

Comment: ну у меня в Visual C++ 2010 компилируется без проблем, под С может не компилироваться так как там переменные надо объявлять в самом начале функции, хоть возможно в новом стандарте уже можно везде.       

А вот переменная объявлена в самом цикле.        
Просто возьмите первый оператор из цикла как отдельный и сразу все станет понятно.


Цикл...

    for(int d = rcount, c = 1; d > 0; d--, c++)

а это первый оператор в цикле...

    int d = rcount, c = 1;